# Containerised celery worker won't start on docker-compose up

Tags: python-2.7, docker, docker-compose, celery

My knowledge to docker is pretty limited so I came here posting this celery worker service won't start with the following error:

> ERROR: for api_worker_1  Cannot start service worker: b'OCI runtime
>   create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process
>   caused "exec: \"worker\": executable file not found in $PATH":
>   unknown'

**DockerFile**

```
# web
FROM python:2.7
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y swig
RUN apt-get install -y libssl1.0-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python", "-u","app.py"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2' 
services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./web:/data/web
      - .:/app
    command: python -u app.py
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"

  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"

  worker:
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: celery worker -B -l info -A app.tasks.celery
    links:
      - db
      - rabbit
      - web
    depends_on:
      - web
```

Looking at the worker service:

```
  worker:
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: celery worker -B -l info -A app.tasks.celery
```

I'm not using/installing the celery from docker. As this is rather a worker image instead of celery image.

This is running with flask application and it was recently working. After cleaning up or deleting images and containers. Running `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` yield the

> OCI runtime create failed:..

Error afterward.

> UPDATE

I updated the title of the question because celery title is misleading here. This is rather a worker service which doesn't have a `DockerFile` on it. It is a service to start a celery worker which resides on `app/tasks/celery`.

Comment: It says that the `celery` command cannot be found. Are you certain you are install `celery` correctly in your image? You're obviously building a custom image here, but you haven't included your Dockerfile in the question.

Comment: It doesn't look as if you're ever installing celery.

Comment: I am not quite familiar with `celery`, but if you have such a file in your container you should consider using the full path to the file inside the container. As celery is obviously not in the path of your container.

Comment: There is no evidence in the information you've posted in this question that you are ever installing celery. Based on what you've posted, the error you're seeing is entirely expected. If you'd like to update your question to include the Dockerfile used to build your celery image, we can probably give you better information.

Comment: @larsks sorry that title is misleading indeed. I'm trying to containerized a celery worker here and not really using a celery image from docker.

Comment: You have a service called `celery` in your compose file which means you are indeed trying to use a Docker image for celery. I'm not sure what you mean by a custom celery file. Is that the Dockerfile that builds the celery image? Perhaps you can post that and we can help

Comment: Guys sorry for a misleading title. I updated my question this is not a celery image. I don't use a celery image from docker. Rather i'm failing to run the celery worker service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your docker-compose file, you have specified the same build context (`build: .`) for both `web` and `worker`. The `Dockerfile` you posted above is being used to build the `web` image AND the `worker` image, and clearly `celery` is not installed in that image.

Comment: Yes absolutely, but if the `web` service will start `worker` should expected to start also.

Comment: Not really. `worker` is using a different startup command (`celery worker -B -l info -A app.tasks.celery`) which is not a valid command in that image, whereas `web` is using `python -u app.py` which is a valid command and therefore it starts up

Comment: I think i'm missing to `pip install -r requirements.txt` here

Comment: Ah. Yeah, add that to your Dockerfile. I'm assuming it has `celery` in it

Comment: Hey it works, damn i really forgot to run `pip install`. Lot of thanks man. saved my day